# Printing a .txt File Python

Tags: python, file, text, printing

I need some help Im trying to display the text files contents (foobar) with this code

```
 text = open('C:\\Users\\Imran\\Desktop\\text.txt',"a")
    rgb = text.write("foobar\n")
    print (rgb)
    text.close()
```

for some reason it keeps displaying a number. If anyone could help that would be awesome, thanks in advance

EDIT: I am Working with Python 3.3.

Comment: You open a text file for writing and expect to read something from it?

Comment: I am a bit curious that it keeps displaying a number, as according to [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) ``write`` will return ``None``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the contents of the file like this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Use `with` to ensure that the file handle will be closed when you are finished with it.

Append to the file like this:

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write('some text')
```

Comment: thanks dude that helped me heaps, I have been dwelling on that question for the past 2 hours

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the contents of the file open it in read mode
`f=open("PATH_TO_FILE", 'r')`

And then print the contents of file using

```
for line in f:
    print(line)     # In Python3.
```

And yes, don't forget to close the file pointer `f.close()` after you finish the reading

Comment: `rgb` is not the file object. `rgb` should be `None`.

Comment: Why not? What is the problem with this approach?

Comment: ``f.readlines()`` keeps all the content in the memory which is not required if you just need a single line at a time. Use ``for line in f:`` to avoid wasting memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the number of written bytes. That won't work. Also you might need to open the file as RW.

Code:

```
text = open('...', "a")
text.write("foo\n")
text = open('...', "r")
print text.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Open a file
fo = open("foo.txt", "r+")
str = fo.read();
print "Read String is : ", str
# Close opend file
fo.close()
```

More: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm